# Can I use steel framing in a shower enclosure

Tags: framing

Turned onto steel framing by a coworker. Part of a wall will extend into a shower enclosure. I will be putting green board over it and then tiling. The coworker seemed to recall using steel in a shower enclosure was problematic due to temperature changes. Anyone have any experience using this and comment further one way or another in regards to using steel framing for a shower? In addition, does anybody see a problem with sheetrocking a ceiling over existing sheetrock? If I pull the existing sheetrock down I have this powdery insulation that is about 2 feet deep that will create a massive mess as it comes raining down.

Answer (score 4):

I've used steel studs in bathrooms many times. The temperature never seemed to be a determining factor.
I personally would hesitate using green board and would use one of the many cement board, wonder boards, that are out there. Structurally, they are much better than the green board and will last longer. Also think about using a water proof coating like Red Guard in the shower areas. There's no problem with adding sheet rock over sheet rock. Just go wall to wall for appearances. You'll need longer screws and will need junction box extenders for any fixtures.

Comment: Thanks Jack. I plan on using a water barrier product to seal the shower. Watched a lot of youtube videos on what sort of board to use for shower enclosures and believe it or not, green board seems to be recommended over backer board or cement board as long as you water proof it. Anyway, thanks again for the response.

Comment: There are many youtube videos. Many of them are wrong, but hey, it's the internet, you can be dead wrong and be a video star.

Comment: I'm looking right at a 2012 Florida codebook that prohibits greenboard and requires cement board for tileing.  I am quite sure many other jurisdictions now prohibit it.  I retiled my shower a decade ago using cementboard and have had no cracks at all in the grout.  Use cement board and use real powered grout with water and use powered cement to glue the tile to the backboard not mastic.  The result of doing it this way is the tile and the cementboard essentially bond together into an extremely rigid wall like a rock wall.  Greenboard will flex and crack all your grout in short order.

Comment: Agree that cement board will provide a better substrate for tile than greenboard. But if youtube says greenboard, then...

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate  Yes, because youtube  knows all. :-)